# What are 'line-arrest' symbols? (Microsoft Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I recently send in a document for correction I created with LibreOffice. I received the correction with the remark that all "line-arrests" have to be removed. Apparently they are introduced because there are "non-MS Word" functions in the document. When I finished my work with LibreOffice I converted the document to .doc, revised it with a recent version of Microsoft Word and sent it in.

Now, I have never heard about line arrests and I cannot see any dubious symbol representing them.

What are they? What is there function and how do I make them visible (within either LibreOffice or Microsoft Word)?

Every answer is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I've heard this term, and neither has Google for that matter. Could you ask the Word user for a [screenshot](http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/)?

Comment: @grawity Yeah, that's why I got stuck ... I'll ask.

Comment: @Dear Downvoter: Please explain how I can expand on my question to make it more clear to you.

Comment: I wonder if they are referring to paragraph markers?

Comment: Perhaps it's "line end" i.e. hard line returns. Could be based on a mistranslation (e.g. I'm not saying between French and English but even between those two languages it's possible to imagine a mixed-language "line end" = "line arrêt" = "line arrest")

Comment: Auto-correction can be a wonderful thing (arret in, arrest out).